# Parsing Spacy's output

Tags: nlp, spacy

I understand spacy is parsing the given sentence and doing a POS tagging for the same.But after the sentence is parsed, i would like to get some sense of the output.

set an alarm for 7 PM tomorrow,

Expected output

```
{
  Intent : set_alarm,
  entity : { "time" : 7PM, "date": tomorrow}
}
```

Output from spacy :

```
[
   {
      word: "Set",
      lemma: "set",
       NE: "",
       POS_fine: "JJ",
       POS_coarse: "ADJ",
       arc: "ROOT",
       children: [
           {
              word: "alarm",
              lemma: "alarm",
               NE: "",
               POS_fine: "NN",
               POS_coarse: "NOUN",
                arc: "dobj",
               children: [ ]
             },
             {
               word: "for",
               lemma: "for",
               NE: "",
               POS_fine: "IN",
               POS_coarse: "ADP",
               arc: "prep",
               children: [
                 {
                   word: "9 pm",
                   lemma: "9 pm",
                   NE: "TIME",
                   POS_fine: "NN",
                   POS_coarse: "NOUN",
                   arc: "pobj",
                   children: [ ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                word: "today",
                lemma: "today",
                NE: "",
                POS_fine: "NN",
                POS_coarse: "NOUN",
                arc: "npadvmod",
                children: [ ]
               }
              ]
             }
           ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output is a [parse tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree). You're also given part of speech information (POS) and recognized named entities (NE). What you provide as expected output is called intent detection as far as I remember, please also see [this](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/230) ticket.